# Is it possible to edit the stylesheet of FireFox Developer Tools?

Tags: styles, developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

Is it possible to edit the visual layout of FireFox's developer tools? I'm talking about the tools themselves, not the webpage that the tools are inspecting.

I want to narrow the large gap between the CSS property name and value:

[image: screenshot of large gap in firefox dev tools]

I've read that [FireFox's UI is built in XUL and CSS](https://www.quora.com/What-programming-languages-are-web-browsers-like-Google-Chrome-Opera-and-Mozilla-Firefox-written-in), so theoretically it should be possible to append a custom stylesheet
but I don't haven't found any info on how to customize the stylesheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible by creating a [`chrome/userContent.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserContent.css) file in the profile directory. [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) can be used to inspect the DevTools elements, similar to how DevTools inspects a webpage.

Mozilla's documentation on `userContent.css` is a bit outdated, so a newer guide like [the one from Dedoimedo](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/firefox-change-ui-tutorial.html) can be helpful. In particular, `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` needs to be enabled in `about:config`.

```
/* Tab contents */
@-moz-document url-prefix("chrome://devtools/content/") {
    .computed-property-view {
        justify-content: space-between;
        column-gap: 20px;
    }

    .computed-property-name-container {
        width: auto !important;
    }

    .computed-property-value-container {
        flex: 0 0 auto !important;;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .computed-property-value {
        padding-inline-start: 0 !important;;
    }
}
```

To change the tab bar itself you'd put styles in `@-moz-document url-prefix("about:devtools-toolbox")`